# How to Summarize record of Array-list of Object

Tags: java, arraylist

please look following problem.

```
    //Bean Class
public class Test {

    private int value;
    private int com_id;

    /**
     * @return the value
     */
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * @param value the value to set
     */
    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * @return the com_id
     */
    public int getCom_id() {
        return com_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param com_id the com_id to set
     */
    public void setCom_id(int com_id) {
        this.com_id = com_id;
    }

}
```

Main Class

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test bean1 = new Test();
        Test bean2 = new Test();
        Test bean3 = new Test();
        Test bean4 = new Test();
        Test bean5 = new Test();

        //bean1
        bean1.setCom_id(1);
        bean1.setValue(10);
        //bean2 
        bean2.setCom_id(2);
        bean2.setValue(50);
        //bean3
        bean3.setCom_id(1);
        bean3.setValue(30);
        //bean4 
        bean4.setCom_id(1);
        bean4.setValue(20);
        //bean5
        bean5.setCom_id(2);
        bean5.setValue(20);

        //Arraylist of Test object
        ArrayList<Test> alltest = new ArrayList<Test>();
        alltest.add(bean1);
        alltest.add(bean2);
        alltest.add(bean3);
        alltest.add(bean4);
        alltest.add(bean5);

    }

}
```

NOW i want ArrayList with sum of all value whose com_id is same as follow
answer_list
com_id = 1; val = 60 (10+30+20)
com_id = 2; val = 70 (50+20)

Comment: That what called logic building and you should learn that by your own .. write Something and even then if you are stuck somewhere show us the code where you are stuck instead of asking solutions directly !

Comment: This is my problem but , i m not asking direct solution . but i tried by many ways, and i am not succeeded that's why i am asking.

Comment: Then at least show what you have tried .. otherwise there are lot's many ways to do this and how can one be sure you understand which way..

Comment: Thanks ankur I done it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the old way with for loops, or do it in one (very long) line using Java 8 Streams:

```
List<Test> aggregated = 
    alltest.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Test::getCom_id,
                                          Collectors.summingInt(Test::getValue)))
           .entrySet()
           .stream()
           .map(e-> new Test(e->getKey(),e->getValue())
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Explanation :

The first part (until the end of the first `collect`) should create a `Map<Integer,Integer>`, where the key is the Test identifier and the value is the sum of values of all Test instances having the same id.

The second part iterates over the entries of that Map and tranforms then to a List of Test instances.

Note this requires adding a constructor to the Test class taking two parameters.

```
public Test (int com_id, int value) {
    this.com_id = com_id;
    this.value = value;
}
```

This is not tested, so it may contain typos.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with, Ankur... but here is at least some hint:

You want some Logic like:

```
tempVar = 0
for all elements in my List:
    if the id of current element is what i need:
        add value of current element to tmpVar
```